# result after applying on delete cascade

Tags: databases

In this table B is foreign key referring to the primary key A with on delete cascade option.What will be the result after deleting (4,3) and how
A:1 4 2 9 3 5
B:3 3 4 2 9 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result will be an empty table.

The steps are :

1. delete (4,3)
2. delete rows with B = 4        --> (2,4), (5,4)
3. delete rows with B = 2, B = 5 --> (9,2)
4. delete rows with B = 9        --> (3,9)
5. delete rows with B = 3        --> (1,3)